# How to check for data in a Mysql database using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I was wondering how can you check to see if certain data is present in a database and if so display it on the web page and if not don't display it using PHP.

Comment: I was looking to select a specific users data?

Answer (score 1):

You select the data and you can use mysql_num_rows() to check how many rows were returned.

If no rows are returned, you can do something else.

Rough unsafe example

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = 20");
$num = mysql_num_rows($query);

if($num > 0)
{
    // Stuff to do when you find the items
}
else
{
    // No items found
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's a pretty involved question. It requires you to connect to your database `mysql_connect()`, query it `mysql_query()`, and pour out any results from the query `mysql_fetch_object()`.

Answer (score 0):

Using the [PHP MySQL interface functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php), you run a [SQL `SELECT` query](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select.html) that will retrieve the data you are looking for.  Using a [PHP control structure such as `if`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php), you then conditionally display the data, or not, depending on its existence or lack thereof.